# Error de sintaxis en Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedure, postgresql-9.3, sintaxis

tengo un problema al compilar, lo que pasa es que me genera error de sintaxis, el detalle es que apenas estoy aprendiendo de los procedimientos almacenados, miren esta es mi función:

Nota: Edité mi pregunta y ya se ejecutó correctamente, solo que volvió arrojar otro error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_insert_update_trabajo_dave_json(
    param_origin_adm character varying,
    in_json text) 
    RETURNS TABLE(var_mensaje varchar, var_success boolean)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
jsonData json;
var_count integer;
var_json json;
var_json_fields json;
var_n integer;
var_mensaje varchar;
var_success boolean:=false;
var_counts integer;
BEGIN
    jsonData := in_json:: json;

    SELECT COUNT (*) from cat_vehicle 
    where cve_vehicle =(jsonData->>'cve_vehicle'):: integer into var_counts;
       IF (var_counts >0)THEN
            UPDATE cat_vehicle SET vehicle_name =(jsonData->>'vehicle_name')
            WHERE vehicle_name=(jsonData->> 'vehicle_name');

    --return 'Json actualizado'
    ELSE
    FOR var_json_fields IN SELECT  * FROM json_array_elements(in_json::json)LOOP    
    INSERT INTO cat_vehicle(
        origin_adm,
        cve_vehicle,
        vehicle_name, 
        cve_brand, 
        vehicle_plate, 
        vehicle_vin, 
        cve_model, 
        vehicle_year, 
        cve_color, 
        vehicle_capacity, 
        cve_type, 
        cve_vehicle_cat,
        vehicle_image,
        status, 
        user_cve, 
        last_update,
        fec_param_ini, 
        lbase_param_ini, 
        odo_param_ini, 
        date_last_man, 
        odo_last_man,
        cve_delivery_route) VALUES(
               (var_json->>'origin_adm') :: integer,
               (var_json->>'cve_vehicle'):: integer,
               (var_json->>'vehicle_name')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'cve_brand'):: integer,
               (var_json->>'Vehicle_plate')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'vehicle_vin')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'cve_model'):: integer,
               (var_json->>'vehicle_year')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'cve_color'):: integer,
               (var_json->>'desc_color')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'vehicle_capacity'):: integer,
               (var_json->>'cve_type')::integer,
               (var_json->>'cve_vehicle_cat')::integer,
               (var_json->>'vehicle_image')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'status')::character varying,
                (var_json->>'user_cve')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'last_update')::character varying,
                (var_json->>'fec_param_ini')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'ibase_param_ini')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'odo_param_ini')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'date_last_man')::character varying,
               (var_json->>'cve_delivery_route')::character varying);

           get diagnostics var_n = row_count;
            if(var_n>0)then 
           var_success:=true;
                var_mensaje:='Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente.';
                ELSE
                var_success:=false;
                var_mensaje:='Error en el sistema favor de contactar a su administrador.';
            END IF;
            END LOOP;
        --ELSE
            var_success:=false;
            var_mensaje:='Error en el sistema favor de contactar a su administrador.';
        END IF;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT var_success,var_mensaje;
END;

$BODY$;
```

El (otro)error es:

```
ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
SQL state: 42804
Detail: El tipo retornado boolean no coincide con el tipo de registro esperado character varying en la columna 1.
Context: función PL/pgSQL sp_insert_update_trabajo_dave_json(integer,text) en la línea 83 en RETURN QUERY
```

Nota: ya revisé y si está regresando en el return query, pero el compilador desconozco por qué no me lo acepta.

Espero y me puedan ayudar, se lo agradeceré enormemente, quedo al pendiente de alguna duda o comentario, saludos

Answer (score 4):

El error es que te indica es que tienes mal la sentencia del **UPDATE**, te hace falta darle el valor con el cual quieres actualizar el campo `vehicle_name`, la sentencia debería de quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE cat_vehicle SET vehicle_name = 'Valor'
WHERE vehicle_name=(jsonData->> 'vehicle_name');
```

Donde `'Valor'` es el valor con el cual vas a actualizar el campo.

Comment: Hola, solo que hay un pequeño detalle, lo que sucede que ese nuevo valor viene de un json, es decir ese json va a ser recibido como parametro que uno pueda modificar

Comment: Solo reemplazas el `'Valor'` por el valor de tu JSON.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, ya lo corregí, ahora probaré la función a ver que me arroja :)

Comment: De nada!! Si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo y ya califiqué, solo un detalle más, ya volvi a editar mi pregunta con otro problema. :(

Comment: ¿Estás seteando el mismo valor que estás buscando? La cláusula WHERE tiene el mismo valor que la cláusula SET.